# how to set default value in formControl?

Tags: angular, form-control, formgroups

I'm trying to set default value for time in an input field, but I couldn't do it using "value" attribute.

```html
<input class="form-control" name="absolute type="time" value="23:59" formControlName="absoluteTime">
```

I tried using

```html
<div [formGroup]="dueDateControl" class="row">
   <input class="form-control style__inputText style__inputText-forms duration" name='absoluteTime' [readonly]="context === 'details'" formControlName="absoluteTime" type="time" required> 
</div>
```

.ts file :

```js
ngOnInit() {
   this.dueDateControl.addControl('absoluteTime', new FormControl('23:59', Validators.required));
}
```

nothing is shown and I still get --:-- ! no default value!

Comment: Does it work if you change the type="time" to type="text"?

Comment: no it doesn't work !

Comment: I see typo in the HTML `name="absolute type="time"`. I suppose it would be `name="absoluteTime" type="time"`. is it typo in the source code or only in the question text?

Comment: has you defined your dueDateControl as `dueDateControl=new FormGroup({});`? else you can not use `addControl`. Looks like work, see the stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4j8xyw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html, if only need a FormControl, use a `[formControl]="name_of_your_FormControl"`

Comment: on satckblitz i see it's working! but not on my machine !

Comment: @SS_FStuck try copy-pasting the logic from the stackblitz in your project line for line and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use it this way

```html
<div [formGroup]="dueDateControl" class="row">
  <input class="form-control style__inputText style__inputText-forms duration" name='absoluteTime' formControlName="absoluteTime" type="time" required>
</div>
```

```
dueDateControl= this.formBuilder.group({
    absoluteTime: [''],
  });
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dueDateControl.get('absoluteTime')?.setValue('19:20')
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Ts File

  newDayDuration: 0;
```

```
<div class="col s4">
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>{{ 'LABEL_DAYS_NEW' | translate: lang }}</mat-label>
      <input  (keypress)="numberOnly($event)"  placeholder="{{'LABEL_TOTAL_DAY_PLACEHOLDER' | translate:lang}}" [maxLength]="vendorRules.DAYS_ENTER_MAX_LENGTH"   matInput   [value]="newDayDuration"  [formControlName]="'newDayDuration'">
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```